# Magento 2 with gatsby grapgql for product view page?

Tags: magento2, javascript, graphql, graph

I am using gatsby js and successfully got the product list in index.js But I need to show the detail of product on click. 
So I used the below code in `gatsby-node.js` file.

```
const path = require('path');
const DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require('directory-named-webpack-plugin');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(
            graphql(
                `
                    {
                        allMagentoProduct {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    url_key
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `
            ).then(result => {
                if (result.errors) {
                    reject(result.errors);
                }

                // Create pages for each product
                result.data.allMagentoProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
                    createPage({
                        path: `/${node.url_key}/`,
                        component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/page-2.js`),
                        context: {
                            url_key: node.url_key,
                        },
                    });
                });
            })
        );
    });
};
```

in my `page-2.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"


const SecondPage = () => (
  <div>

    <h1>Hi from the second page</h1>
    <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
    <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
  </div>
)

export default SecondPage

export const query = graphql`
    query ProductQuery($url_key: String) {
        allMagentoProduct(url_key: { eq: $url_key }) {
            id
            sku
            name
            description
            small_image
            image {
                childImageSharp {
                    fluid(maxWidth: 1024, maxHeight: 1024) {
                        src
                        srcSet
                        sizes
                        aspectRatio
                        base64
                    }
                }
            }
            categories {
                id
                name
                url_path
            }
            configurable_options {
                label
                values {
                    label
                    value_index
                }
            }
            url_key
            price {
                regularPrice {
                    amount {
                        value
                        currency
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

But I get below

```
there was an error in your GraphQL query:

Cannot query field "allMagentoProduct" on type "Query".

File: gatsby-node.js:51:12


 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'allMagentoProduct' of undefined



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'allMagentoProduct' of undefined

  - gatsby-node.js:71 graphql.then.result
```

I couldn't understand the flow of gatsby with grapqh

Comment: was the answer helped you or you found any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call allMagentoProduct in graphQl query.
I guess hope your GraphQl shema is look like this.

```
type Query {
ProductQuery (
    url_key: String @doc(description: "url_key")
): [allMagentoProduct] @resolver(class: "Vendor\\YourMOdule\\Model\\Resolver\\Yourresolver") @doc(description: "The productsdata ")


type allMagentoProduct @doc(description: "all Attributes to show in Product Details Page") {
   id : String  @doc(description: "Custom Product's Attributes array"
   sku : String  @doc(description: "Custom Product's Attributes array"
   name : String  @doc(description: "Custom Product's Attributes array")
-- your other return values -- 
}}
```

so this kind of grapgql schema you want to write the Query as below

```
query ProductQuery{
   ProductQuery( url_key : "product-url-key") {
     id
     name
     sku
 }
}
```

No need to pass the return type variable(allMagentoProduct) in the query. Just try and see.You may follow this [magento blog](http://www.mujahidh.com/) regarding grapqhql for some custom tasks.